# R, How to extract blocks of values from correlation similarity matrix?

Tags: r

I have a correlation similarity data frame, for example the one shown below:

```
      1         2         3         4
1 1.0000000 0.9991846 0.7648333 0.3517951
2 0.9991846 1.0000000 0.7563048 0.3569311
3 0.7648333 0.7563048 1.0000000 0.6568740
4 0.3517951 0.3569311 0.6568740 1.0000000
```

I'd like to extract the clusters of values that are above a certain threshold (0.95,in this case). So that I'd have the following returned each one as separate data frames:

```
      1         2        
1 1.0000000 0.9991846 
2 0.9991846 1.0000000 

      3
3 1.0000000 

      4
4 1.0000000
```

I have thought about subsetting or using logical operators, such as:

```
subset(blah, blah[1,] >.95)
blah > .95
```

Which I think is the right direction, but I'm kind of stumped as to how to approach this problem? Any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: I forgot to add that the correlation similarity matrix will always be sorted by the angular order of eigenvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with no looping:

```
mytableTxt <- "      1         2         3         4
1 1.0000000 0.9991846 0.7648333 0.3517951
2 0.9991846 1.0000000 0.7563048 0.3569311
3 0.7648333 0.7563048 1.0000000 0.6568740
4 0.3517951 0.3569311 0.6568740 1.0000000"
mytable <- read.table(textConnection(mytableTxt), header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
mytable <- mytable[mytable > .95]
newbloc <- mytable==1 & c(1, mytable[-length(mytable)])==1
blocid <- rep(1:sum(newbloc), c(which(newbloc), length(newbloc) + 1)[-1] - which(newbloc))
blocsplit <- split(mytable, factor(blocid))
lapply(blocsplit, function(x)
    tmp <- as.data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = max(c(1, length(x)/2)))))
# $`1`
#          V1        V2
# 1 1.0000000 0.9991846
# 2 0.9991846 1.0000000
# 
# $`2`
#   V1
# 1  1
# 
# $`3`
#   V1
# 1  1
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. But ideally  you wouldn't define the number of clusters there are going to be however when you hardcode in the number of reps you essentially do this (i.e the number of clusters there will be). I wonder if there is a way around this. I'll let you know if I figure it out. Thanks again I would have never have figured out your way. Best

Comment: Thanks! I corrected a typo I just noticed and changed it so that it works on any object, without the hard-coded "3" in the rep(). New line starts with `rep(1:sum(new bloc), ` which is the number of `TRUE`s in that vector, representing the non-diagonal elements above your threshold of 0.95.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a a complete answer but it still uses a loop and a few ifs:

```
#clusters ordered correlation similarity matrix
#takes csm and threshold as input
man_cluster_threshold <- function(M.AOE, threshold = .95){
   list_of_clusters <- list()
   y <- 1
   for(x in 1:ncol(M.AOE)){
    #if its not the last column this will check to see if the value to the right is below the theshold 

       if(x != ncol(M.AOE)){
          if(M.AOE[x,x+1] < threshold){
             #if it is below the threshold then that block of the matrix gets saved as its own block
                 qwer <- as.data.frame(M.AOE[y:x,y:x])
                 name_trans <- colnames(M.AOE[])[y:x]
                  y <- x + 1
                  names(qwer) <- name_trans
                list_of_clusters[[x]] <- qwer
              }
         }
       # if it is above the threshold
        else{
             qwer <- M.AOE[y:x,y:x]
              list_of_clusters[[x]] <- qwer
       }
        #this checks the last transcript
     if(x == ncol(M.AOE)){
          if(M.AOE[x,x-1] < threshold){
           #if it is below the threshold then that block of the matrix gets saved as its own block
                qwer <- as.data.frame(M.AOE[y:x,y:x])
                name_trans <- colnames(M.AOE[])[y:x]
                y <- x + 1
                names(qwer) <- name_trans
                  list_of_clusters[[x]] <- qwer
                 }
              }
            }
               list_of_clusters <- rmNullObs(list_of_clusters)
                return(list_of_clusters)
           }
```

Anybody have a better idea?